# Pass a Javascript Class in MongoDB MapReduce scope to be used by map

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I wrote a class Student in Javascript.

```
function Student(info) {
  this.getName(info);
  this.getAge(info);
}

Student.prototype.getName = function(info) {
  this.name = info.name;
};

Student.prototype.getAge = function(info) {
  this.age = info.age;
};
```

Now, I need this class inside the map function of mongoDB mapReduce framework. That is,

```
var mapFunction = function() {
  var student = new Student(this);
  emit(student.name, student.age);
};
```

This function map doesn't have access to Student defined outside this function. Therefore, I need to pass this class through scope of mapReduce.

```
var scopeVar = { Student: Student};
db.collection.mapReduce(
   mapFunction,
   { 
     scope: scopeVar,
     out: { merge: 'testCollection'}
   }
);
```

However, turns out that inside map, we have Student defined but the Student.prototype is empty. To test this I wrote alternative mapTest,

```
var mapTest = function() {
  emit(Student, Student.prototype);
};

var scopeVar = { Student: Student};
db.collection.mapReduce(
   mapTest,
   {
     scope: scopeVar,
     out: { merge: 'testCollection'}
   }
);
```

In db.testCollection, one can see that output document looks like this

```
{_id: function Student(info) {
  this.getName(info);
  this.getAge(info);
}, 
 value: {}
}
```

Therefore, it seems that somehow scope doesn't copy the prototype of the object.

If one wants to define helper functions as prototype function of the class, how can one pass it through the scope of mapReduce?

Comment: Why not just do the simple thing and include the source inside the map function?

Comment: I would also suggest you consider keeping the code as fast and simple as possible. Is a full object necessary?

Comment: I agree that is the simple and easiest solution. However, there are reasons against it. If the class is very complicated with several prototypal functions, then it is better to keep them separated for code management.

Comment: I'd be very concerned that you're trying to put too much logic in your map reduce functions if it's truly that complex. Maybe what you're saying is true with a normal JavaScript project, but Mongo and Map Reduce aren't the same environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My hypothesis is that MongoDB is implemented in C, the CLI or execution engine reads the code and submits it to the V8Engine. So, the interpreted context of Prototype is not perceived by the CLI and hence is not submitted to V8 Engine. The scope paramater enhances the parameter mechanism, but does not give the full dynamic nature as expected. Internally, mongodb must be creating another function with given scope. To achieve what you mentioned, I would try something like this:

This should work.

```
var scopeVar = { Student: Student, StudentPrototype: Student.prototype };

var mapFunction = function() {
Student.prototype = StudentPrototype;
var student = new Student(this);
    emit(student.name, student.age);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Above answer is correct in the approach. The correct answer is following.

```
var scopeVar = { Student: Student, StudentPrototype: Student.prototype };

var mapFunction = function() {
  Student.prototype = StudentPrototype;
  var student = new Student(this);
  emit(student.name, student.age);
};
```